# Finding cell reference in For loop

Tags: regex, excel, reference

I am running a `regex` text to find invalid data in a range. I want an error message box to display the location of the error when it is found as the data sets are large.

So far my for loop is:

```
For Each cell In rng1

    Dim vntData As Variant
    vntData = cell
    If Not (regtext.test(vntData) Or cell.value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Failed to validate data [" & vntData & "] in cell E" & n & ".", vbExclamation, "Regular Expressions"
        cell.Select
        Exit For
    End If
    If n < 100000000 Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

This does the required job. However I would prefer to have a general cell reference (rather than specifying "E") since I need to use it in several different cases. 
Is there a way to get the cell reference from the variable "cell" in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell.address`.  MSDN docs on this method are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625%28v=office.15%29.aspx), or see the VBA help file within Excel.